Unable to Connect to Postgres DB through PHP(7.4) in Windows server
I host my PHP page in Windows IIS, Uncommented the pgsql extensions in php.ini file, restarted the services/machine. stil getting the below error in my php page,
Connection failed. Error message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" after "ls.crt" in connection info string
below is my code,
<?php

$host = "wer.wp-postgres-prd01.carbon.abc.com";
$port = 41101;
$dbname = "****";
$user = "****";
$password = "****";

$sslcert = "D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\windows\pgcerts\tls.crt";
$sslkey = "D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\windows\pgcerts\tls.key";
$sslrootcert = "D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\windows\pgcerts\ca.crt";

$conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=41101 dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password sslmode = require sslcert=$sslcert sslkey=$sslkey sslrootcert=$sslrootcert");

if (!$conn) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "Connection failed. Error message: " . $error['message'] . "\n";
    }
else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}

?>


\t inside a double-quoted string represents a tab character. To avoid that, use a single quote delimiter for $sslcert, $sslkey and $sslrootcert.

Thank you for the response, I declared those 3 variables in single quote, but then now it says it requires valid certificate.  Error message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate

Question: If you put all the certificates into the same folder as your current PHP script and then remove all those directory paths with backslashes, what happens ?

It worked..! Thanks a lot..! $sslcert = "tls.crt";
$sslkey = "tls.key";
$sslrootcert = "ca.crt";
